# Best way(performance wise) to concat multiple columns - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

Is there a better way(best performance) to approach a large concat on multiple columns.

fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b196/2

```
 CREATE TABLE Table2
(
  PersonName varchar(64),
  Address1 varchar(64),
  Address2 varchar(64),
  Address3 varchar(64),
  Postcode varchar(64),
  PhoneNumber int,
  EmailAddress varchar(64)
  )

  INSERT INTO Table2 (PersonName, Address1, Address2,Address3,Postcode, 
  PhoneNumber,EmailAddress)
    VALUES 
    ('Sam','1 Smith Road', 'Portmouth', 'UK','IO45 7AD', 
    '304974','123@hotmail.com');
```

Query:

```
  SELECT 
  PersonName,
  Address1,
  Address2,
  Address3,
  Postcode,
  PhoneNumber,
  EmailAddress,

  CONCAT(PersonName, + ' ',
  Address1, + ' '

,
  Address2, + ' ',
  Address3, + ' ',
  Postcode, + ' ',
  PhoneNumber, + ' ',
  EmailAddress) AS [Customer Address]
  FROM [Table2]
```

Result:

```
| PersonName |     Address1 |  Address2 | Address3 | Postcode | PhoneNumber |    EmailAddress |                                              Customer Address |
|------------|--------------|-----------|----------|----------|-------------|-----------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|        Sam | 1 Smith Road | Portmouth |       UK | IO45 7AD |      304974 | 123@hotmail.com | Sam 1 Smith Road Portmouth UK IO45 7AD 304974 123@hotmail.com
```

Ive seen some approaches with case statements but is there a better approach with any improved performance? Any advice or opinions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: You are selecting all rows from a table.  The performance will be dominated by the full table scan.

Comment: Like @GordonLinoff said, the issue isn't going to be `CONCAT` here. I *suspect* your real table has a lot more than 1 row in it, but do you really need all those rows? If you want "better" performance, then consider adding a `WHERE` (it's more that the SQL Server has to do a lot less work, as it doesn't need to return every row). You might also then need appropriate indexes for any `WHERE` clauses you have. If you *do* need every row, then there's unlikely a lot you can do, but then such queries are normally for ETL, and thus are offline and/or infrequent (so performance is a lower priority).

Comment: You can use `CONCAT` or `+` to concatenate strings in SQL Server. Which you pick shouldn't really matter. I wouldn't give it another thought. (Your `CONCAT(PersonName, + ' ', ...` however, precedes every blank with a plus sign, which does effectively nothing (I guess it is taking the postive of the character code, which already is positive). You should remove it.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I would argue that choice is very important. `a + b + c` and `CONCAT(a,b,c)` can and do give difference results as they act differently. Using `+` with any `NULL` value will return `NULL`, however, `CONCAT` will never return `NULL`, and will concatenate all the non-NULL values: For example: `SELECT a + b + c, CONCAT(a,b,c)
FROM (VALUES('abc',NULL,'123')) V(a,b,c);` The first expression returns `NULL`, however, the second `'abc123'`.

Comment: @Larnu: Ah, I didn't know that. So it's definitely worth a thought, which to use. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . The `+`is ignored.  That rather surprises me.  I thought `+` was a no-op unary *numeric* operator, so it would attempt to convert the string argument to a number.  But it appears to be a no-op for string arguments too.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Well, I was just as surprised seeing that query running :-)